# Syntax error when trying to use "iplantuml" in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plantuml

I'm trying to use plantuml in jupyter notebook within VS Code.

```
pip install iplantuml

import iplantuml
%%plantuml

@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```

Keep getting this error:

```
Cell In[3], line 5
    Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I hover over the `import iplantuml` I see this error:

> "iplantuml" is not accessed Pylance

I can generate a plot using matplotlib. It is only plantuml I'm unable to use

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%%plantuml` magic command should be the first line in its cell.

Here's how you could structure your cells:

```py
# Cell 1
!pip install iplantuml
```

```py
# Cell 2
import iplantuml
```

```
# Cell 3
%%plantuml
@startuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('plantuml', '', '@startuml\nAlice -> Bob: Authentication Request\nBob --> Alice: Authentication Response\n@enduml\n'))

.......
<br>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @jas What's Cell[10]? I think this new error report deviates from the original question, you can try to open a new issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll mark it as answered and open a new thread for the new issue